# How to do RTL with django-easy-pdf

Tags: django, pdf-generation

I'm using django-easy-pdf in a project to provide an output report.  Works great.  I'm just adding Hebrew to the languages available and I cannot get the output in RTL.

I've tried a number of approaches to force RTL formatting including hard-coding

```
            html, body, p, table, tr, td, span {
                direction: rtl;
            }
```

within the  tags in base.html.

Does django-easy-pdf support RTL and if so, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: use `django-weasyprint` instead